# Editing terrain generated randomly in Javascript with cursor

Tags: javascript

I'm making an University project and at the moment I have this randomly generated terrain. It simply gets a random value with some limits to it, puts it into an array and then i use lineTo(i,array[i]) to show me the world.

It works as intended, but now I'd like to be able to edit this "map" with my cursor if I enter let's call it "Edit Mode". At the moment I have a button that makes me enter this mode and then I check this:

```
function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
    var relativeX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    var relativeY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
    if(relativeX < canvas.width && dragging && editing && relativeY < world[relativeX] + 20 && (relativeY > world[relativeX])) {
        removeWorldPart(relativeX);
}

function removeWorldPart(coordinate){
    for(var i = 0; i< 5; i++) {
        if(coordinate > world[coordinate] + 5 || coordinate > world[coordinate] - 5) {
            world[coordinate+i] += 6-i;
            world[coordinate-i] += 6-i;
        }
    }
```

So what I'm trying to achieve (numbers can be set easily) is that like a little circle from the array that stores all those heights of my random world gets modified a bit. 
It does change the heights in "world[]" but not really as a circle and probably I'm missing something else.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Your condition should be an (approximation of) circle equation. You're using a square at the moment, which is why it's "not really as a circle".

Comment: I thought that removing X and then moving to the side and removing X-i was a fair close-hit to a circle.. But it gets very spiky, looks like the function gets called maybe too slow so I should change approach? I'll try to calculate an approximation tho and see the results as soon as I get home :)